# error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "void *" в "RGBTRIPLE *"

Tags: c

Столкнулся с ошибкой при выделении памяти под структуру в Си. Вот строчка, на которую указывает ошибка компиляции:

```
RGBTRIPLE* StringPixels = malloc((abs(biCopy.biWidth) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)));
```

`RGBTRIPLE` это структура для пикселей:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} RGBTRIPLE;
```

Если кому не понятно, могу кинуть полный код. Сам код пробую скомпилировать на VS 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` возвращает указатель типа `void *` для последующего использования его необходимо явно привести в нужный тип, например так:

```
RGBTRIPLE* StringPixels = (RGBTRIPLE*) malloc((abs(biCopy.biWidth) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)));
```

Comment: `c` допускает неявное преобразование указателей из `void*` в `T*`.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы компилируете сишный код компилятором `c++`. В `c` допускается неявное преобразование `void*` (который возвращает `malloc`) в `T*`, а вот в `c++` это уже запрещено.

Поэтому, если код именно сишный, нужно и исходник компилировать как сишный. Для Visual Studio для этого обычно достаточно изменить расширение файла на `.c`.

Если же требуется обеспечить сборку в режиме `c++`, то требуется явное приведение типов, о котором уже сказано в другом ответе.